# What is the best Linux distribution for someone who have been on Windows OS for years?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows-10

I want to change from Windows OS to Linux OS but I don't know the best distribution for me. I use my PC for writing blogs and doing some light coding.

I was going to install Kali but then I found out that it is not suitable for beginners and it is very specific for persons who practice cyber security.

Comment: You are asking for uninformed opinions: We don't know what you like, we don't know your skills.

Comment: You tagged Kali, which is not designed to be used as a desktop OS.

Comment: As a beginner, you can try Ubuntu or Linux Mint. This is a QA website for Ubuntu, and Mint is not supported here.

Comment: +1 for realizing kali is not for beginner and has a specific purpose. :D

Comment: The best (*no such thing, but closest*) will depend on many factors you've not provided including how you'll use your setup, what apps you'll run, and if a desktop system your actual tastes.. I admire your seeking help with such an issue, but it should have been done on a forum & not a Q&A (*Question & Answer*) site where it's off-topic ...  https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forum(s)... *Opinions are off-topic on Q&A sites like this*

Answer (score 4):

Well, since this is specifically an Ubuntu-related site, we're probably going to toot our own horn and suggest that you try a few of the official Ubuntu flavors.

When you boot the Ubuntu installer, you will have the option to "Try Ubuntu" without installing. Do so.

Test your hardware. Test the look and feel. Take your time. Use it all day. Stream a movie. Do some work. Look for any rough edges.

Then try another.

**NO** Linux distro is a drop-in replacement for Windows. That means that they may be fully-capable operating systems, but behave differently from Windows. They cannot be made to behave like Windows -- you must adapt and learn (like we did).

Your Windows software won't work without extra add-ons, and some Windows software simply won't work at all.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the expression "toot our own horn"! 